# Syntax check on x86 Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I am new to assembly, and I am getting all kinds of syntax errors in my code. I would like some help sorting them out. The Code is as follows:

```
.model flat,c
.code

; extern "C" int CalcResult1_(int a, int b, int c);

CalcResult1_ proc
    push ebp
    mov ebp,esp

    mov eax,[ebp+8]
    mov ecx,[ebp+12]
    mov edx,[ebp+16]

    add eax,ecx
    imul eax,edx
    pop ebp
    ret
CalcResult1_ endp
    end
```

The errors are as follows:

> 1>------ Build started: Project: CompOrgHW2, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
>
> 1>Assembling assembly_.asm...
>
> 1>assembly_.asm(1): error A2044: invalid character in file
>
> 1>assembly_.asm(2): error A2008: syntax error : .
>
> 1>assembly_.asm(6): error A2008: syntax error : C
>
> 1>assembly_.asm(7): error A2008: syntax error : p
>
> 1>assembly_.asm(8): error A2008: syntax error : m
>
> 1>assembly_.asm(10): error A2008: syntax error : m
>
> 1>assembly_.asm(11): error A2008: syntax error : m
>
> 1>assembly_.asm(12): error A2008: syntax error : m
>
> 1>assembly_.asm(14): error A2008: syntax error : a
>
> 1>assembly_.asm(15): error A2008: syntax error : i
>
> 1>assembly_.asm(16): error A2008: syntax error : p
>
> 1>assembly_.asm(17): error A2008: syntax error : r
>
> 1>assembly_.asm(18): error A2008: syntax error : C
>
> 1>assembly_.asm(19): error A2008: syntax error : e
>
> 1>assembly_.asm(19): error A2088: END directive required at end of file
>
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\BuildCustomizations\masm.targets(69,5): error MSB3721: The command "ml.exe /c /nologo /Zi /Fo"Debug\assembly_.obj" /W3 /errorReport:prompt  /Taassembly_.asm" exited with code 1.
>
> 1>Done building project "CompOrgHW2.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
>
> ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: What assembler are you using? With which program are you editing the asm file?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 17 with masm

Comment: It looks like there's some type of confusion about how the file is stored (unicode vs ansi).  If the file is marked as ansi, but actually contains unicode, I'd expect you'd get behavior like this.  Try recreating the file.